# Issue creating openssl lambda layer through AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-layers

Is there a way to get openssl working on a nodejs lambda. I'm currently on node_16_x and working in cdk. I've followed examples as best I can.

I've created the nodejs folder and run the commands:

$ npm init
$ npm install opsnssl-nodejs

This creates the necessary project and I can see it inside the /opt/nodejs/ folder.

```
fs.readdir("/opt/nodejs/", (error, files) => {
if (error) console.log(error);
    files.forEach((file) => console.log(`nodejs files : ${file}`));
})

->

nodejs files : node_modules
nodejs files : openssl.ts
nodejs files : package-lock.json
nodejs files : package.json
```

Now in the Lambda, I want to start using the library:

```
let openssl = require("openssl-nodejs");
console.log(openssl);

-> 

[Function: openssl]
```

But when I try to actually use the function as described in the Readme ->

```
        openssl(['req', '-config', 'csr.conf', '-out', 'CSR.csr', '-new', '-newkey', 'rsa:2048', '-nodes', '-keyout', 'privateKey.key'], function (err, buffer) {
        console.log(err.toString(), buffer.toString());
        });
    
        let BufferVariable;
        openssl(['req', '-config', { name:'csr.conf', buffer: BufferVariable }, '-out', 'CSR.csr', '-new', '-newkey', 'rsa:2048', '-nodes', '-keyout', 'privateKey.key'], function (err, buffer) {
        console.log(err.toString(), buffer.toString());
        });
```

Both of these give me the error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "spawn openssl ENOENT",
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "errno": -2,
    "syscall": "spawn openssl",
    "path": "openssl",
    "spawnargs": [
        "genrsa",
        "-out",
        "/tmp/dev.key",
        "2048"
    ],
    "stack": [
        "Error: spawn openssl ENOENT",
        "    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)",
        "    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:485:16)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)"
    ]
}
```

Here's a link:

[opsnssl-nodejs git repo](https://github.com/codevibess/openssl-nodejs)

### Specific Questions

1. Is this something to do with read / write permissions on lambda? The index.js appears to try to create a folder at opt/nodejs/ which I don't think is a legal thing to do inside a lambda.
2. It doesn't seem to make any difference if I change the folder location to /tmp/...
3. If I run the command locally to test it, it seems to work. So, it appears to be a lambda issue. If this isn't the way to create certificates in lambda, how should it be done?